# Insert row from CSV file2 in file1 if row is unique in file1 (according to a common key)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two csv files that have the same structure. `tops.csv` and `yesterday.csv`. I am first sorting yesterday by a specific column than I want to take the row with the highest value in that column. For this row, I want to check 3 of its columns, (the 3rd fourth and fifth columns) and see if there is a row in tops.csv that has the same data in the same columns. So i am checking for duplicates in those 3 columns. If a row with the data already exists, the row we found should be skipped and proceed to the next highest/valid row by the sort column until one is found which does not already have data in `tops.csv`. If there is no row already, I want to write the row to a csv called `for_email.csv` and also append that row to `tops.csv` where we checked for its existence.

This is the script I have so far with comments for each step

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Replace 'your_file.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
file_path = 'yesterday.csv'

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)

# Sort the DataFrame by last column and then by the 2nd column from the left
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[-1], df.columns[1]], ascending=[False, True])

# Drop duplicates based on all columns except the first one, keeping the first occurrence
df_sorted_no_duplicates = df_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset=df_sorted.columns[2:])

# Read the 'tops.csv' file to check for existing data
tops_df = pd.read_csv('tops.csv', header=None)

# Initialize a counter for the number of rows written to 'for_email.csv'
rows_written = 0

# Open the 'for_email.csv' file for writing
with open('for_email.csv', 'w', newline='') as for_email_file:
    for index, row in df_sorted_no_duplicates.iterrows():
        # Check if the third, fourth, and fifth columns of the current row exist in 'tops.csv'
        if not tops_df[tops_df.columns[2:]].eq(row.iloc[2:]).all(axis=1).any():
            # If not, write the row to 'for_email.csv'
            for_email_file.write(','.join(map(str, row)) + '\n')
            rows_written += 1

            # Break the loop when 3 rows have been written
            if rows_written == 1:
                break

print(f"{rows_written} rows have been written to 'for_email.csv'")


# Open the 'for_email.csv' file for reading
with open('for_email.csv', 'r') as for_email_file:
    # Read the content of 'for_email.csv'
    for_email_content = for_email_file.read()

# Append the content of 'for_email.csv' to 'tops.csv'
with open('tops.csv', 'a', newline='') as tops_file:
    tops_file.write(for_email_content)

print(f"{rows_written} rows have been appended to 'tops.csv'")
```

Here is a sample of my tops.csv

```
Ale Mary's,3.45,Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee,Prison City Pub & Brewery,174906,Stout - Imperial / Double,11.0,4.7619,21,1,4.63971
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52608
Ale Mary's,3.45,Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021),Anchorage Brewing Company,13756,Barleywine - Other,15.5,4.48663,2569,0,4.4862
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52604
```

Here is a sample of my `yesterday.csv`

```
Ale Mary's,3.45,Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee,Prison City Pub & Brewery,174906,Stout - Imperial / Double,11.0,4.7619,21,1,4.63971
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52604
Ale Mary's,3.45,Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021),Anchorage Brewing Company,13756,Barleywine - Other,15.5,4.48663,2569,0,4.48604
Ale Mary's,3.45,Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%,Goose Island Beer Co.,2898,Stout - Imperial / Double,14.7,4.46902,49672,0,4.46887
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2017),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.8,4.44884,88500,0,4.44872
Bartari,3.22,Utopias Barrel-Aged 120 Minute IPA,Dogfish Head Craft Brewery,459,IPA - Imperial / Double,17.0,4.44246,7565,1,4.44017
```

When I run it with this data, I am getting back this row:

`Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52604`

which already exists, yet I should be getting back this one:

`Ale Mary's,3.45,Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%,Goose Island Beer Co.,2898,Stout - Imperial / Double,14.7,4.46902,49672,0,4.46887`

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```py
# 'outer' merge (w/ `yesterday` sorted), adding indicator column (`_merge`) for origin rows
tops = pd.merge(tops, 
              yesterday.sort_values(by=[10, 1],
                                    ascending=[False, True]),
              how='outer', 
              indicator=True
              )

# check dupls `3, 4, 5`, check "right_only", select inverse of both `True`
m = tops.duplicated([3,4,5])
n = tops['_merge'].eq('right_only')
tops = tops[~(m&n)]

# check dupls `_merge` (indicator column), "right_only"
o = tops.duplicated('_merge') & n[tops.index]

# select inverse of both `True`, and drop indicator column
tops = tops[~o].drop('_merge', axis=1)

# row to write away to "for_email.csv"
for_email = tops[n[tops.index]]
for_email.to_csv("for_email.csv", index=False)
```

**Outputs**

```py
print(tops)

                       0     1                                        2  \
0             Ale Mary's  3.45          Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee   
1  Coopers Seafood House  2.99    Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015)   
2             Ale Mary's  3.45  Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021)   
3  Coopers Seafood House  2.99    Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015)   
5             Ale Mary's  3.45  Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%   

                           3       4                                 5     6  \
0  Prison City Pub & Brewery  174906         Stout - Imperial / Double  11.0   
1       Founders Brewing Co.     549  Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee  11.2   
2  Anchorage Brewing Company   13756                Barleywine - Other  15.5   
3       Founders Brewing Co.     549  Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee  11.2   
5      Goose Island Beer Co.    2898         Stout - Imperial / Double  14.7   

         7      8  9       10  
0  4.76190     21  1  4.63971  
1  4.52617  58194  0  4.52608  
2  4.48663   2569  0  4.48620  
3  4.52617  58194  0  4.52604  
5  4.46902  49672  0  4.46887
```

```py
print(for_email)

            0     1                                        2  \
5  Ale Mary's  3.45  Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%   

                       3     4                          5     6        7  \
5  Goose Island Beer Co.  2898  Stout - Imperial / Double  14.7  4.46902   

       8  9       10  
5  49672  0  4.46887
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to create an 'outer' merge for `tops` and `yesterday` (sorted as required), and set `indicator` to `True` to get the source of a particular row: `"left_only"` (tops), `"right_only"` (yesterday), or `"both"`.
- Next, create two boolean Series:

  1. `m`: [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for columns `3, 4, 5`.
  2. `n`: [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `"right_only"` in indicator column `"_merge"`.
- Delete all rows with both `m` and `n` as `True`, by selecting the inverse (using the unary operator `~`): `tops = tops[~(m&n)]`. We have now added from `yesterday` only those rows that were not yet present in `tops`.
- Next, we create another boolean Series (`o`) that checks for duplicates on the indicator column `"_merge"`, but we are only interested in the rows that originate from `yesterday`. Therefore, we add re-indexed `n` (re-indexed, because `tops` has now (potentially) been downsized, missing index values from original `n`).
- Of `o` we need the inverse to keep the correct rows from merged `tops`. At this stage, we can drop the indicator column `"_merge"`, as it is no longer needed.
- Finally, the added row from `yesterday` that needs to be saved as `"for_email.csv"` can now be selected by simply doing: `tops[n[tops.index]]`.

**Data used**

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv1 = """Ale Mary's,3.45,Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee,Prison City Pub & Brewery,174906,Stout - Imperial / Double,11.0,4.7619,21,1,4.63971
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52608
Ale Mary's,3.45,Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021),Anchorage Brewing Company,13756,Barleywine - Other,15.5,4.48663,2569,0,4.4862
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52604"""

csv2 = """Ale Mary's,3.45,Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee,Prison City Pub & Brewery,174906,Stout - Imperial / Double,11.0,4.7619,21,1,4.63971
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.2,4.52617,58194,0,4.52604
Ale Mary's,3.45,Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021),Anchorage Brewing Company,13756,Barleywine - Other,15.5,4.48663,2569,0,4.48604
Ale Mary's,3.45,Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%,Goose Island Beer Co.,2898,Stout - Imperial / Double,14.7,4.46902,49672,0,4.46887
Coopers Seafood House,2.99,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2017),Founders Brewing Co.,549,Stout - Imperial / Double Coffee,11.8,4.44884,88500,0,4.44872
Bartari,3.22,Utopias Barrel-Aged 120 Minute IPA,Dogfish Head Craft Brewery,459,IPA - Imperial / Double,17.0,4.44246,7565,1,4.44017"""

# creating `dfs`
tops, yesterday = [pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), header=None) 
                   for df in [csv1, csv2]
                   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without Pandas, you can create a simple function which takes a row from either tops or yesterday and returns the *key* data (columns 3-5):

```py
Row = list[str]


def lookup_key(x: Row) -> tuple[str, str, int]:
    """Compare/identify row by cols 3-5."""
    return (x[2], x[3], int(x[4]))
```

As you loop over tops, and then yesterday, you'll call this to identify and compare the rows.

I also defined an alias for `list[str]` (the value of a "row" returned by the csv module's reader), named Row.

Start by reading tops into a dict of just the lookup_keys:

```py
def from_csv(fname: str) -> list[Row]:
    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        return list(csv.reader(f))


tops = from_csv("tops.csv")
lookup = {lookup_key(x): None for x in tops}

print(lookup)
```

and you can see the structure of lookup:

```py
{
    ('Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee',         'Prison City Pub & Brewery', 174906): None,
    ('Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015)',   'Founders Brewing Co.',         549): None,
    ('Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021)', 'Anchorage Brewing Company',  13756): None,
}
```

(Your tops sample had 4 rows, but rows 2 and 4, `...,Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015),Founders Brewing Co.,549,...`, are dupes so that key only shows up once in the dict.)

Next read and sort yesterday.  The sort_key func takes the second and last columns, converts them to floats, and multiplies the first column by -1 so that first column will actually sort descending:

```py
def sort_key(x: Row) -> tuple[float, float]:
    """Sort rows by Col11 descending, then Col2 ascending."""
    return ((float(x[10]) * -1), float(x[1]))


yesterday = from_csv("yesterday.csv")
yesterday.sort(key=sort_key)
```

This sorted version of yesterday now looks something like:

```
Ale Mary's            3.45 4.63971 - ('Barrel Aged Wham Whams - Coffee',         'Prison City Pub & Brewery', 174906)
Coopers Seafood House 2.99 4.52604 - ('Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2015)',   'Founders Brewing Co.',         549)
Ale Mary's            3.45 4.48604 - ('Wendigo - Double Oaked (Batch 2 - 2021)', 'Anchorage Brewing Company',  13756)
Ale Mary's            3.45 4.46887 - ('Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%', 'Goose Island Beer Co.',       2898)
Coopers Seafood House 2.99 4.44872 - ('Kentucky Breakfast Stout (KBS) (2017)',   'Founders Brewing Co.',         549)
Bartari               3.22 4.44017 - ('Utopias Barrel-Aged 120 Minute IPA',      'Dogfish Head Craft Brewery',   459)
```

Finally, loop over sorted-yesterday, looking up each row by-key in lookup.  If the key isn't found that means the current row from yesterday is unique and can be added to tops:

```py
the_row = []
for x in yesterday:
    if lookup_key(x) not in lookup:
        the_row = x
        break
```

the_row looks something like:

```
Ale Mary's 3.45 4.46887 - ('Bourbon County Brand Stout (2018) 14.7%', 'Goose Island Beer Co.', 2898)
```

You can then append the_row to the original tops list, and write it out.  I always recommend never to write over a file if it's the input to the current process: write to a new file, then when you're happy with the result move/rename it:

```py
tops.append(the_row)

with open("tops-new.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(tops)
```